# Open eml attachments inline in WLM

Tags: thunderbird, windows-live-mail

I use Mozilla Thunderbird but my secretary uses Windows Live Mail.

If I forward messages to her, it's usually as an attached eml file to preserve the original message's formatting and attachments. Unfortunately for her, **WLM does not expand eml attachments** inline and she has to double click forwarded messages just to open them each time. As I usually forward more than two dozen messages each day for printing and archiving, it can be quite a chore for her.

Is there a way to "fix" WLM so that it can display eml inline? BTW, she has tried TBird but still preferred using WLM so I can't force her to switch.

I'm using TBird 24.6.0 on Windows 7 Home Premium, and she's using WLM 2012 (Build 16.4.3528.0331) on Windows 7 Home Basic

Comment: Hi Dan and welcome. Try to specify the version of Thunderbird and Windows Live Mail that you are using. You can edit your post with the _edit_ link below the tags or with this [link](http://superuser.com/posts/777132/edit).